# Can't send the value from Jquery to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Each time I run this code, I get "VALUE IS EMPTY" message. Means the variable won't pass from Jquery to PHP variable `$value`. I need to pass it to PHP. Help me!

(`#popup` is a div which show up when a table tr is clicked. )

HTML+PHP Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="popup">

     <?php
        if (isset($_POST['val']) && !empty($_POST['val'])) 
        { 
        $value = $_POST['val'];
        echo $value;
        }
        else{
            echo "VALUE IS EMPTY";
            //each time I get this msg.. means it won't take the variable value to PHP
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

JQuery/Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tableview tbody tr').click(function(){

    var a=[];
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    a.push($(this).text());

    });

            $('#popup').show();
            $.ajax({
              url:'addfile.php',
              data:{'val': a[1] },
              type:'post',
              success:function(res){
               //Is there an error due to this function? or what?
              }

            });
});
});
```

-->There is no need to insert the code for the table.. hope this clarifies my question

Comment: Are you using a model popup or simple div?

Comment: So `console.log(a)`, what do you see?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman .. it's simple div

Comment: @u_mulder ... basically 'a' is an array which gets all the values from TD's of a specific TR in the table. And it returns those values

Comment: _where_ do you see "VALUE is EMPTY"??

Comment: @Jeff in the div called #popup.. because i've used the php code in there

Comment: And does this array contain index 1? `console.log(a[1])` shows what you expect?

Comment: you mis-interpret how ajax works!!

Comment: @u_mulder  yes, the array has upto a[8] values

Comment: @Jeff help me then

Comment: the php should be a _seperate_ script (without the html). in your ajax you'll get back what that script echos - in success-funtion in value `res`

Comment: @Jeff made a separate page for the php script and tried again... still not working

Comment: I checked an alert() in the success-function and that alert also shows up.. but the value is not able to be sent ... dont know why

Comment: Have you also changed type to method?

Answer (score 1):

ok, so here's a quick, basic guide:

Your html page, let's name it index.html (different to the php script!):

```
// index.html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="popup"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tableview tbody tr').click(function(){

        var a=[];
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
            a.push($(this).text());
        });

        $('#popup').show();
        $.ajax({
          url:'addfile.php',
          // HERE's A CRITICAL CHANGE:
          // val MUST NOT be in quotes. You're creating a plain object here
          data:{ val: a[1] },
          // you can change that from type to method (default is get) - though type is an alias for method, so both should work.
          method:'post',
          success:function(res){
               // here you have your data back from php, do with that what ever you need.
               console.log(res);  // will show value of a[1] in console
               // my guess is, you want to show it in #popup
               $('#popup').html(res);
          },
          error: function(error, status, errorString) {
               // allways check for possible errors!
               console.log(error);
               console.log(errorString);
          }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Your php script

```
<?php
// adfile.php
if (isset($_POST['val']) && !empty($_POST['val'])) { 
        $value = $_POST['val'];
        echo $value;
} else {
        echo "VALUE IS EMPTY";
}
// don't add a closing tag....
```

*Finally:* Please read about how ajax is proposed to work and read the [manuals](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)!

Comment: Thanks.. I read about ajax and what I found was the 'url" in ajax code specifies where you want your variable to be tested. E.g you pass the variable to another php page and after the variable is done some processsing there, you get the variable back in the form of  $_POST['val']. 
But here, in my case I don't want the variable to pass it to another page. I'm on the same page and want the jquery variable to be sent to the same page where I clicked on a TR. So I also removed the 'url' section from ajax code but didn't work

Comment: Check this and you'll fully understand.
Screenshot 1:  http://i.imgur.com/ye4Y1Wd.png
Screenshot 2:  http://i.imgur.com/oj64l5o.png

Comment: you cannot pass the variable back to the same page (as php var), because there's no php involved anymore. Once the page is loaded, no more php... php is on the server only. Go with my snippet and fill the #popup _after_ you get the vars back.